# Iterate values into different elements based on corresponding class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while and I'm close, but somewhere I'm missing a step.

***Objective:***

> I'm trying to get the contents of a sidenav-which has lists and
>   sub-lists-and then output those contents in the same groups of lists
>   in the footer. HTML and jQuery below.
>   
> EDIT to clarify my objective:
>   I would like some input like this (I'm not sure how to associate these two values using java?):
>   Section 1 : Part A
>   Section 1 : Part B
>   Section 2 : Part C
>   Section 2 : Part D
>
> To output like this:
>   **Section 1**
>   - Part A
>   - Part B
>   **Section 2**
>   - Part C
>   - Part D

The HTML for the sidenav looks like this:

```
<li class="nav-section-one"><a href="/section-one/">Section One</a>
    <ul class="sub-side-page-list">
        <li class="nav-part-a"><a href="/section-one/part-a/" class="section-one">Part A</a></li>
        <li class="nav-part-b"><a href="/section-one/part-b/" class="section-one">Part B</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-section-two"><a href="/section-two/">Section Two</a>
    <ul class="sub-side-page-list">
        <li class="nav-part-c"><a href="/section-two/part-c/" class="section-two">Part C</a></li>
        <li class="nav-part-d"><a href="/section-two/part-d/" class="section-two">Part D</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'm trying to achieve an output in my footer that looks like this:

```
<div class="column">
    <h3>Section One</h3>
    <ul class="footer-column-section-one">
        <li><a href="/section-one/part-a">Part A</a></li>
        <li><a href="/section-one/part-b">Part B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <h3>Section Two</h3>
    <ul class="footer-column-section-two">
        <li><a href="/section-two/part-c">Part C</a></li>
        <li><a href="/section-two/part-d">Part D</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm actually ending up with is output like this:
**Section 1**

Part A

Part B

**Section 2**


Part A

Part B

Part C

Part D

I'm getting the contents of the previous output every time I iterate through the loop. I just want A and B in Section 1, and C and D in Section 2, and so forth. How can I iterate just the results I want to their associated sections? The script I have so far is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var mainNavItems, subNavItems, subNavItemsParent, mainNavLength, subNavLength, mainNavList, subNavList, mainNavItemsText, subNavItemsText, subNavLinks, subNavItemsLinks, subNavItemClass, i, val;
    mainNavItems = ( $( "#doc-nav .side > li > a" ).toArray() );
    subNavItems = ( $( "#doc-nav .side > li ul li a" ).toArray() );

    var newHTMLmain = $.map(mainNavItems, function(value) {
        return ("<div class='column'><h3>" + value.text + "</h3><ul class='footer-column-" + value.text.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, "-") + "'></ul></div>");
    });
    $("#directorynav").html(newHTMLmain.join(""));

    var newHTMLsub = "";
    $.each(subNavItems, function(i, val) {
        newHTMLsub += "<li><a href='" + val.href + "'>" + val.text + "</a></li>";
        $( ".footer-column-" + val.className ).html( newHTMLsub );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here. Can you simplify your problem a little?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to output a main list element, with several sub-lists inside the main list. The sub-lists have different quantities of list items inside them. I want to be able to take something like:

Section 1 : Part A
Section 1 : Part B
Section 2 : Part C
Section 2 : Part D

and get:

Section 1
- Part A
- Part B
Section 2
- Part C
- Part D

Is that more clear?

Comment: You want section 1 to be output multiple times for each part A and part B or just one time?

Comment: I would like section 1 to be output just once, with part A and B; then section 2 also output once with parts C and D; and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this way i am parsing your HTML.

```js
var _html = "";
$("li[class^='nav-section']").each(function(){
  _html += '<div class="column">';
  _html += '<h3>'+$(this).find("a").eq(0).html()+'</h3>';
  _html += '<ul class="footer-column-section-one">';
  
  $(this).find("li").each(function(){
    var _link = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    var _text = $(this).find("a").html();
    _html += '<li><a href="'+_link+'">'+_text+'</a></li>';
  });
  
  _html += '</ul>';
  _html += '</div>';
});

console.log(_html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-section-one"><a href="/section-one/">Section One</a>
  <ul class="sub-side-page-list">
    <li class="nav-part-a"><a href="/section-one/part-a/" class="section-one">Part A</a></li>
    <li class="nav-part-b"><a href="/section-one/part-b/" class="section-one">Part B</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-section-two"><a href="/section-two/">Section Two</a>
  <ul class="sub-side-page-list">
    <li class="nav-part-c"><a href="/section-two/part-c/" class="section-two">Part C</a></li>
    <li class="nav-part-d"><a href="/section-two/part-d/" class="section-two">Part D</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!! I think the key was the $(this).find("li").each(function() you wrote within the first .each loop, that selects only the li elements that are lower in the DOM from top li.nav-section-*. Much appreciated. Marked answered :)